# How can I modify the state of a React/Redux component from outside?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a regular HTML-page with an input element used for filtering, and a React component that manages and displays a table of items. When the user types in the input element I want the React component to apply the filter to it's state. How to I pass this information to the React component, and make it "react" on it? The HTML page belongs to an application, and cannot be React-ified.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make a React component update is by updating it's props. So, you need to add a prop to the React component that you can use to update when you make changes to the input. That will pass the new data to the component and it will re-render.

So wherever the React component lives, you need to pass in a variable when you change the text in the input.

```
let filter_string = '';
input.on('keyDown', e => filter_string = e.target.value)

<Items filter={filter_string} />
```